# Get user's authorities in the XML

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, javabeans

I am trying defining this bean in my spring xml configuration:

```
<bean id="aclAuthorizationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref=""></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

which needs as parameter a list of `GrantedAuthority` objects. Is it possible get the list of authorities of the logged user and use as parameter here?

Comment: Programatically, you can retrieve authorities by doing: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()`, not sure which bean you should refer to from XML, or maybe try some java based configuration

Comment: @zakariaamine programatically i already knew how to do, but i wanted avoid add a class just to do it. i am wondering if there is a way to access this data from the xml.